# How can i work around the ValueError from random.sample in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, random, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to write a code for a Knapsack problem. Where there is a knapsack with a weight capacity and you pick a certain combination of items to find the best possible solution. However, i'm trying to randomly generate the possible solutions. So my code will pick a random number of random items (generate a random sized list) and test to see if the solution is feasible (less than the capacity) or infeasible (more than the capacity). But i'm having problems with the random.sample(). In order to get a random sized list, I set k to be leng (a random integer) and the population is a random list of items picked from the range of the items given. But I know that if leng is larger than the population, then there is a ValueError. I want to use random.sample() so I can have a list of unique numbers, but I need to work around the ValueError somehow. I've tried doing try: and except ValueError: but I'm not sure how to really carry it out. This is what I have so far:

```
def genSoln(cap, items)
    g = input("Would you like to generate random potential solutions? [y/n] ")
    if g == 'y':
        gen = int(input("Number of times to generate/check random potential solutions? "))
        totalwt = 0
        totalval = 0
        for i in range(1,gen+1):
            try:
                pop = range(1,items)
                leng = random.randint(1,8)
                ran = random.sample(pop, leng)
            except ValueError:
                pass
            for i in ran:
                totalwt += int(wts[i])
                totalval += int(vals[i])
                if i == len(ran):
                    if totalwt < int(cap):
                        print("Items picked: ", ran)
                        print("Feasible: ", "Total Wt = ", totalwt, "Total Val = ", totalval)
                    else:
                        print("Items picked: ", ran)
                        print("Infeasible: ", "Total Wt = ", totalwt, "Total Val = ", totalval)
                    totalwt = 0
                    totalval = 0
```

Comment: instead of hard coding the upper limit of leng why dont you use the size of pop as the upper limit?

Comment: So do... `ran = random.sample(pop, len(pop))`?

Comment: yes or even just: `ran = random.sample(pop, items)`, presuming items is an integer

Comment: Oh... I just realized. The thing with that is that it produces the same sized list. I did the `leng = random.randint(1,8)` because the code is going to produce multiple random generations and the random generations need to be.. Well.. Random in size.

Comment: sorry your right, that is why initially i said change the upper limit of leng, i.e `leng = random.randint(1,len(pop))`

Comment: Okay. That worked. Thank you~! But also... You wouldn't happen to see anything else wrong with my code would you? I keep getting the wrong total wt and wrong total val when I run the code.

Comment: @Calum Please submit `leng = random.randint(1, items)` as the answer so Destiny can  accept it and other reviewers will know this is answered.  I could do it but do not want to 'steal' the rep that should go to you.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt Terry

Comment: @DestinyBrown Regarding your 2nd question. Can you add some examples of the data and results you are using. And i also suggest you create it as a new question to stay within the guidelines

Comment: @Calum Okay, i'll make a new question. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thsi should do it.

```
leng = random.randint(1, items)
```